# Теги на кириллице из xml

Tags: java, xml, кодировка

```
File xml = uploadPortletRequest.getFile("file");
BufferedReader fis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                  new FileInputStream(xml), "UTF-8"));
Document document = SAXReaderUtil.read(fis);
document.getDocument().normalize();
document.getDocument().setXMLEncoding("UTF-8");
document.setXMLEncoding("UTF-8");

Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();

for (Element element : rootElement.elements()) {
    System.out.println(element.getName() + "==" + element.getName().getBytes().length);
    if (element.getName().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Ид")) {
        System.out.println("!!!!!!!");
    }
}
```

Вот сам xml файл:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <classifier>
        <name>articleId</name>
        <value>29006</value>
    </classifier>
    <preference>
        <name>groupId</name>
        <value>20181</value>
    </preference>
    <id>7777</id>
    <Ид>4bda4442-08dd</Ид>
```

В консоли:

```
    classifier==10
    preference==10
    id==2
    Ид==4
```

То есть, знаки '!!!!!!!' возле тега не появились, на equals не проходят теги на кириллицы. Почему? Сам xml файл пробовал по разному преобразовать.

Comment: Скорее всего, исходник компилировался без указания кодировки.

Comment: ваш xml не является синтаксически верным. так же укажите какой SAX Parser вы используете.